# Node-Red- Cathing Error in installation the db2

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, db2-connect

I need to connect my db2 database to node-red. when i try to install node red contrib db2 for i, I get error that the platform is not compatible with windows. do I need to install aix? I could install node red contrib db2 fixed on my node-red on win7-x64. may i connect db2 with this node?
Thank you

Comment: Where is your db2 instance hosted? Is it on iSerise? If not you are using the wrong node

Comment: I use db2 on ibm cloud. with which node I can load my database on node-red?

Comment: Try node version 8. node-red-contrib-db2 package is not compatible for latest versions of node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [node-red-contrib-db2-for-i](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-db2-for-i) is specifically for working with DB2 on iSeries systems.

If  you want to connect to a "normal" DB2 database then you can use either:

- [node-red-contrib-db2](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-db2)
- [node-red-contrib-db2-fixed](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-db2-fixed)

Comment: thank you. I could install node-red-contrib-db2-fixed on my local node-red, but on node-red cloud i couldnt. I got this error:   ReferenceError:  primordials is not defined at fs.js:35:5 at req_ (/home/vcap/app/.node-red/node_modules/natives/index.js:143:24)

Comment: That wasn't what you asked in the question, you asked how to install for windows not IBM Cloud